# MySQl Error #1064 in stored procedure by limit

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '_from , _rowcount ORDER BY id DESC; END' at line 4

with this query:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_works_selectcustom(IN _from int,IN _rowcount int)
BEGIN
   SET NAMES UTF8;
   SELECT id, title, time, price, discription, date
   FROM works
   LIMIT _from , _rowcount
   ORDER BY id DESC;
END$$
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Your snippet ends with a delimiter of `$$`, but you don't appear to have set that. Try adding `delimiter $$` as the first line. Remember to set `delimiter ;` after you finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of MySQL are you using?

From the documentation: [13.2.9. SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)

> ...
>
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
>   integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL
>   5.5.6.
>
> ...

In MySQL 5.5.32 works, see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3a837/1), changing to version 5.1.61 error is generated.

Comment: Thanks. What do i for old mysql version?

Comment: For older versions are commonly used [13.5. SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation on a SELECT statement in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) the LIMIT clause comes *after* the ORDER BY clause...

```
SELECT id, title, time, price, discription, date 
  FROM works
 ORDER BY id DESC 
 LIMIT _from , _rowcount
```

Comment: Thanks. but After Change:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '_from , _rowcount ; END' at line 5

Comment: You've seen [wchiquito's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19757725/458741)... there's your answer ot that problem.